# How to use fetch to fetch data from AWS RDS in a react application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services

I'm learning Node + React. In my Node + React application, I have the following component `FetchData.js` to fetch data from `localhost`:

```
import React from 'react';

class FetchData extends React.Component {

    static async getData() {
        let response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/my-project');
        let body = await response.json();
        return body
    }
}

export default FetchData;
```

I could see the json objects by typing `localhost:4000` in the browser.

Now I'm hosting the data in AWS RDS. I have an endpoint like this:

```
my-project.abc12345def.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
```

How can I fetch data from the endpoint like what I did in `FetchData.js`? I tried to replace `localhost` with the endpoint url, no luck; tried to type the endpoint url in a browser, could not see its content. I suppose I need to be able to see its content to be able to fetch data?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you most simple difference

Fetch is a way to access HTTP resources like `http://localhost:4000/my-project`.

Your RDS endpoint (Most probably MYSQL) does not run an HTTP server.

So these endpoints (Links) are different, and they are not for the same purpose.

Edit:
You could connect to RDS using a MYSQL client from your server running on  `http://localhost:4000` which then return the data to fetch request.

Comment: Any idea how to get an url from the endpoint so I could put it in the fetch function?

Comment: Thank you, I have connected RDS with MySQLWorkbench, but not sure how to do the rest.